# awk substitute column value if not equal to either of 2 values

Tags: regex, awk, conditional-statements

I am working with a TAB separated file, as follows:

```
+    +    +
-    +    .
+    +    -
+    +    &
+    -    )
```

I want to replace column $3 with "NA", but only if it is not equal to either "+" or "-".

The file should be changed to look as follows:

```
+    +    +
-    +    NA
+    +    -
+    +    NA
+    -    NA
```

I have tried the following, but it does not work.

```
cat $file |  awk 'FS=OFS="\t"{ if ($3 !="+" && $3 != "-" ); print }'
```

How can I do the above?

Comment: `it does not work` is the worst possible problem description. Just like if you drop your car off at a garage to be fixed, you've got to tell us in what way `it does not work` so we can best help you fix your code and explain your problem so you'll know better next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close. You may use:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} $3 !~ /^[-+]$/{$3="NA"} 1' file
```

```
+   +   +
-   +   NA
+   +   -
+   +   NA
+   -   NA
```

Comment: Thanks so much anubhava! I understand all the code except for the "1" at the end. What is this for?

Comment: That is used to print all the records.

Answer (score 1):

with `sed` it's easier...

```
$ sed -E 's/[^+-]$/NA/' file

+    +    +
-    +    NA
+    +    -
+    +    NA
+    -    NA
```

Comment: Thanks karakfa, however, this will substitute in columns other than column $3. If there was a non "+/-" symbol in another column ,this would be replaced, which must be avoided in my case

Comment: Not any column, only the last one as in your example.  However, in real case if it's not the last column it's not going to work.